# How to do complex validation in laravel across multiple fields?

Tags: forms, laravel

I have a form that requires you to enter an address. The fields requested are:

1. street address
2. suburb
3. postal code

Individual validation on these fields are easy. You can simply use "required" and "min" etc to make sure that it's filled in. But I need a third validation option that does the following:

1. build a string consisting of these three parameters
2. pass these fields to a service called "addressValidator"
3. confirm if the address is "overall" valid
4. place the error message only under one of the fields (street address) if they all fail

How would you create such a validator on a form?

Answer (score 0):

just extend the validator

EDIT: and your message bag method

```
private $moreMessages = array();

public function postStore()
{
    ...
    ...
    if($validator->passes())
    {
         ...
         ...
         // pass data to the other validator...
         if($this->extendedValidator($data))
         {
           /// yaay!! i can store now!
         }
         else
         {
             return Redirect::to('')->with('messages',$this->moreMessages);
         }
    }
}

private function extendedValidator($data = array())
{
   $passed = true;
   // if validator address fails
       // $passed = false;
       // $this->moreMessages['address'] = 'blabla';

   // if validator birthday fails
       // $passed = false;
       // $this->moreMessages['birthday'] = 'blabla';

   return $passed;
}
```